# check what is clicked then condition and if nothing then condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load a view based on what button is clicked. Of course when the first landing on the page load will be nothing clicked, and it will load specific view. But when user click one of some buttons, the first view will be replace by the view based on what is clicked.

Here is what I have been trying.

```
$(".pagesbutton").click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    if($('.pagesbutton').data('clicked')) {
      buttonpressed = $(this).attr('id');
      if(buttonpressed == 'one') {
        //will load the view of one
      }
      else {
        //will load the view of two
      }
    }


    else {
        //will load the view of default
        //it is the first land of the page load when nothing is clicked. 
    }
});
```

When the first time page is load, the jquery only alert the `default` view. But after that, when I click all button, it doesn't alert anything.

Comment: I think that you misunderstand the click event.

Comment: When the first time page is load, the jquery only alert the default view. But after that, when I click all button, it doesn't alert anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO - JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/01zys5gr/)

I think your JQuery should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.theView').prepend('The default view!');
});

$('.pagesbutton').on('click', function() {
   $('.theView').empty();
   var buttonpressed = $(this).attr('id');
   if (buttonpressed == 'one') {
      $('.theView').prepend('The view of One!');
   }
   else {
      $('.theView').prepend('The view of Two!');
   }
});

<div class="theView">this is one view bla bla bla with css class and id</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to remove the previous view as your comment in the code?

Comment: Post your HTML so I can see what we are doing, I don't know what the view is right now.

Comment: the view is only `<div>this is one view bla bla bla with css class and id</div>`

Comment: Do I need a `wrapper` here to do the `prepend` function?

Comment: Nope, it adds the content at the beggining of the ".theView" <div> element. I added a JS Fiddle so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You want to bind to the click event of the element, then use attribute data to get a page and load it into an element:

[*Note - please see the code example comments for additional observations*]

```js
// bind to class link event
// this will fire when a '.link' element is clicked.. not just div
// open console to see logs

$('.link').click(function() {

  // this = element clicked
  console.log($(this));

  // get data-* attribute value
  var pageRef = $(this).attr('data-page');
  console.log(pageRef);

  // [Note] jQuery.data() is not the same as data attribute
  // attr = DOM, data = javascript object
  // example:
  console.log($(this).data('page'));
  // same as pageRef
  // but..
  $(this).data('page', 'nonsense');
  console.log($(this).data('page')); // nonsense
  console.log($(this).attr('data-page')); // foo

  // just be consistent with attr - data
  // load the page?
  loadPage(pageRef);

});

// helper!
function loadPage(ref) {
  $('#loader').empty(); // removes everything there before
  // load the page:
  //$('#loader').load("/" + ref);
  $('#loader').html(ref);
}
```

```css
div{
    display : inline-block;
    border: dashed 2px steelblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.link{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#loader{
  display : inline-block;
  border: solid 2px pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-page="foo"><a href="#">foo</a>
</div>
<div class="link" data-page="bar"><a href="#">bar</a>
</div>
<div class="link" data-page="baz"><a href="#">baz</a>
</div>
<div id="loader">Loading data...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is something you might want:

```
$(".pagesbutton").click(function(){
    // replace the view, you might want something like this
    $('#some_div').text('clicked by pagesbutton');
});

$(".otherbutton").click(function(){
    $('#some_div').text('clicked by otherbutton');
});
```